# jQuery Datetime Picker onSelect not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using jQuery's datetime picker to pick **Start** and **Finish** dates, after selecting `Start` date I want automatically open `Finish` date picker. I've found 2 events: `onClosed` and `onSelect` to listen and programatically open another picker, heres my code:

```
 $('#StartDate').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $('#FinishDate').focus();
        }
    });
```

My problem is that programaticaly opened `FinishDate` date picker closes itself immediately(If I use this `('#FinishDate').datepicker('show')` instead of `focus` doesn't work either). 
If I listen to `onClose` event instead it works great, `Finish` date picker shows up and "stays".

But this event will occur even if user does not choose `Start` date and I want to open finish dialog **only** after start is picked.

```
onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $('#FinishDate').focus();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `if` condition

```
onClose: function (selectedDate) {
    if(selectedDate)
        $('#FinishDate').focus();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4UAJ3/5/